# Using pos_weight to improve recall in a multi-class multi-label problem

Tags: neural-networks, classification, precision-recall, multi-class, multilabel

I have a multi-label classification problem, and so I’ve been using the Pytorch's [BCEWithLogitsLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#bcewithlogitsloss). I’d like to optimize my model for a higher F2 score, and so want to bias it to have greater recall (with decent precision too of course). Are there any guidelines for setting the values of `pos_weight` to be able to do this?

Answer (score 2):

While adjusting `pos_weight` does change the model, and may therefore change the association between predicted probabilities and labels, it doesn't have any direct influence on the F2 score itself. Indeed, for a *multi-class* and *multi-label* problem, it's not even clear which class or label would be a "positive."

Instead, F2 score depends on the precision and recall of the model's predictions. The precision and recall are, in turn, binarizations of the model's predicted probabilities. You can change the F2 score directly by changing the choice of threshold.